# Azure Data factory transformation pipeline take more than 5 minutes to execute when there are Data Flow activity with Transformation

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-data-factory

I'm have created a pipeline with a data flow activity which is concatenating two fields in my input file. My input file contains 5 rows of data and 4 Fields. I'm creating these things through visual studio using .net SDK. When I create this job and run it, it's taking more than 5 minutes to execute. What I feel it's internally enabling the Data Flow debugger and that's why it's taking that much of time. Just want to know is my answer is correct or not. If not please tell me why it's taking that much of time even for 5 records? Thanks

Comment: I think so, when we are runing  data flow, it must run the Data Flow Debug first, it will take serval minutes. When the pipeline execution finished, we can see the really cost time of the data copy in pipeline output json in details.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use a Data Flow within ADF it has to provision the Integration Runtime for the Data Flow.  You will always incur this spin-up time when Data Flows are involved.

(If you have multiple sequential Data Flows within the same pipeline, the first Data Flow will always incur the spin-up time, but if you set Time to Live (TTL) on the Integration Runtime config you can have subsequent Data Flows use that initial runtime and skip the spin-up time on the downstream Data Flows which fire within the TTL window.)

With just a single Data Flow, reevaluate whether you absolutely need it.  If you don't, then you can remove it and skip that spin-up time.  But, if you need the Data Flow there is no way to avoid that initial spin-up.